# failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 403

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I am trying to make two ajax calls to get amazon servers link and after that I am trying to play it in a modal but getting this I don't know how to solve or is there any other way in first ajax call I am taking the url from my own server and by that url's page I am trying to get amazon server's link after that I am trying to play a video i.e. on that link but it's not working

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.activityinstance').click(function(){

          var url = $(this).find("#mod_id").attr('data-link');
$.ajax({
type : 'post' ,
url : url ,
data : {flag:'ajax'},

success: function(result){

      $.ajax({
           type : 'get' ,
           url : result ,

success: function(data){
data=data.substring(0, data.indexOf("4"));
console.log(data);
$("#Mdlheader").html(data);
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
   file: data,
});
}
});
}
    });
});
});
</script>
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">

   <!-- Modal content-->
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       <h4 id="Mdlheader" class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
<div id="myElement"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     </div>
   </div>
 
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console to see where the error is?

Comment: Also 403 is usually signifying that you don't have permission for whatever you requested. You sure you got your auth tokens/key/whatever set properly?

Comment: I am working with moodle so every error it will show in view page @sideroxylon

Comment: yeah I've got that still giving me error but I've got some solution thanks for helping @Zlatko